# Regex to remove everything after -i- (with -i-)

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I was trying to find solution for my problem.

```
 Input: prd-abcd-efgh-i-0dflnk55f5d45df

 Output: prd-abcd-efgh

Tried Splunk Query : index=aws-* (host=prd-abcd-efgh*) | rex field=host "^(?<host>[^.]+)"| dedup host  | stats count by host,methodPath
```

I want to remove everything comes after "-i-" using simple regex.I tried with regex "^(?[^.]+)" listed here

https://answers.splunk.com/answers/77101/extracting-selected-hosts-with-regex-regex-hosts-with-exceptions.html

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace(host, "(?<=-i-).*", "")`

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/blcCcQ/2

This `(?<=-i-)` is a [lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: This works but it prints with "-i-" at end  prd-abcd-efgh-i- Will it be possible to print without -i-

Comment: sure then it's `replace(host, "-i-.+", "")`

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of Splunk. but the normal way to do that would be to match the part you don't want and replace it with an empty string.

The regex for doing that could be:

```
-i-.*
```

Then replace the match with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this should work:

```
([a-z-]+)-i-.+
```

The first capture group will return only the part preceding `-i-`.